# How to fetch the address of few places on google map which show unavailable with given lat,lng

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a problem which relates to geocoding in which using google geocode map api with given lat,lng (for example 32.983025 75.710981),the return result gives status as ZERO_RESULT. How can we handle this find to find the address for that particular lat,lng, which should be understandable by the end user.

[image]

Comment: Those coordinates aren't close enough to a postal address for google to return a result.  They do seem to be the coordinates of a place though ("vasuki nag temple vasak dhera")

Comment: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/orhnrsft/))

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the returned result. If the status is not OK then you can give an error message saying that the address was not found.

```
<status>OK</status>
```

You can also validate the input and inform the user that it needs to be in "lat, lon" format

Answer (score 0):

Can check the status but it will be not user friendly as the address might be there but google map doesn't suggest any address as it might not be added or it might be newly added to map. So in order to handle you will check the status from the geode api and validate before showing to the end user.